# SNMP4j agent snmp table

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I have created on SNMP agent using snmp4j api but getting issue with snmp table registration

Once i register a table and and rows in table. and after that if i set the values in table all the rows got set with same value.
I have snmp table created from JSON

In below table if i set value

.1.3.6.1.4.1.1.201.6.2. it set the values for all the rows that are registered in below table. Does anyone aware of how to register and set the values properly using snmmpj agent.

```
{
        "tableName": "table1", 
        "tableId": ".1.3.6.1.4.1.1.201.6.1", 
        "columns": [
            {
                "columnName": "column1", 
                "columnOID": 1, 
                "dataType": 70, 
                "accessType": 1,
                "defaultValue":0
            }, 
            {
                "columnName": "column2", 
                "columnOID": 2, 
                "dataType": 70, 
                "accessType": 1,
                "defaultValue":0
            }, 
            {
                "columnName": "column3", 
                "columnOID": 3, 
                "dataType": 70, 
                "accessType": 1,
                "defaultValue":0
            },

        ]
    }



 public static MOTable<MOTableRow<Variable>, MOColumn<Variable>, MOTableModel<MOTableRow<Variable>>> createTableFromJSON(
        JSONObject data) {
    MOTable table = null;

    if (data != null) {
        MOTableSubIndex[] subIndex = new MOTableSubIndex[] { moFactory
                .createSubIndex(null, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_INTEGER, 1, 100) };
        MOTableIndex index = moFactory.createIndex(subIndex, false,
                new MOTableIndexValidator() {
                    public boolean isValidIndex(OID index) {
                        boolean isValidIndex = true;
                        return isValidIndex;
                    }
                });
        Object indexesObj = data.get("indexValues");
        if(indexesObj!=null){
            String indexes = data.getString("indexValues");
            String tableOID = data.getString("tableId");
            JSONArray columnArray = data.getJSONArray("columns");
            int columnSize = columnArray.size();
            MOColumn[] columns = new MOColumn[columnSize];
            Variable[] initialValues = new Variable[columnSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnSize; i++) {
                JSONObject columnObject = columnArray.getJSONObject(i);
                columns[i] = moFactory.createColumn(columnObject
                        .getInt("columnOID"), columnObject.getInt("dataType"),
                        moFactory.createAccess(columnObject
                                .getInt("accessType")));
                initialValues[i] = getVariable(columnObject.get("defaultValue"));

            }

            MOTableModel tableModel = moFactory.createTableModel(new OID(
                    tableOID), index, columns);

            table = moFactory.createTable(new OID(tableOID), index, columns,
                    tableModel);
            String[] indexArrString = indexes.split(";");
            for(String indexStr: indexArrString){
                MOTableRow<Variable> row = createRow(new Integer(indexStr.trim()), initialValues);
                table.addRow(row);
            }
        }
        }

    return table;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, OIDs do not start with a dot (as specified by ASN.1).

Second, you do not seem to use any row index data. Rows are indentified by their indexes. A row index is the instance identifier suffix of a tabular instance OID:

```
<tableOID>.1.<rowIndex>
```

The  can consists several sub-index values encoded as OIDs.